# Finding compact sets.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I am trying to find all (non-finite) compact sets in the following topology.

On the set, X=$\mathbb{Z}$, and the topology, $\tau_x$={$\mathbb{Z}$, $\emptyset$, all sets containing 7 but not 8}.

*attempt*:

1. Find all (non-finite) compact sets.

The trouble that I am having is that I know that in *any* topology, finite sets are compact. My thought for this example is that there are no (non-finite) compact sets.

Suppose there are infinite compact sets, that is I can construct an infinite set $A$ with the property that $A \subset \cup_{\alpha\in A}^{j}$ {$\alpha$, 7}. Since $A$ is an infinite set, a finite subcover for $A$, say $B$, will contain only a finite number of elements which in this topology will be singleton sets $B$={$\beta$, 7|$\beta \in \mathbb{Z}$}. A finite set cannot cover an infinite set which is a contradiction that $A$ has a finite subcover and thus not compact. Therefore, the only compact sets in this topology are finite sets.

I am hoping that someone can point me in the right direction about understanding this question and helping me construct a nice proof.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

any set containing 8 is compact.

Proof: any cover must contain an open set that contains 8. There is only such open set : Z. So it has a finite sub-cover consisting of Z.

Done.

You showed above the case for infinite sets not containing 8.

Comment: Why are we considering 8 but not 7?

Comment: Is the reason because if we consider an infinite set $B={x_{1},x_{2},...}$ with $B \subset \cup_{\alpha\in B}^{j}$, the only open set covering $B$ would be $\mathbb{Z}$ because if $8 \in B$ then the sets containing 7 but not 8 would _not_ be a cover, and this leaves only $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: the only open set that contains 8 is Z.  So any open cover must have Z as an of its elements.

Comment: Ok, that makes much more sense. Thank you.